# Create a list of values from type-level list

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

I have a type-level list like this

```
data TList (ixs :: [*]) (f :: * -> *) where
  TNil  :: TList '[] f
  (:-:) :: f ix -> TList ixs f -> TList (ix ': ixs) f
```

And I'm trying to generate a new TList using an existing one.
The idea is to have a function

```
genTList :: TList ixs f -> t -> TList ixs g
```

where 't' is some function able to construct a value of type 'g x' where 'x' is one of types form the list 'ixs'.

So that given

```
data Foo x
```

and (some kind of)

```
generate :: forall x . Bar x
```

I could get something like this

```
genTList (Foo Int :-: Foo String) generate = Bar :-: Bar
```

So essentially for every item 'x' in the type list I want to have a type 'Bar x' 
and also construct its value with parameterless constructor, because I know 
that 'Bar x' doesn't have constructor parameters.

I tried to implement something (https://gist.github.com/lolepezy/30820595afd9217083c5ca629e350b55) but it wouldn't typecheck (reasonably).

So how should I approach the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define

```
class TListGen ixs (g :: * -> *) where
  genTList :: Proxy ixs -> g ix -> TList ixs g
```

but this means that the caller of the function can choose what to instantiate all of the type variables with, so in particular also how to instantiate `ix`.

So for example,

```
genTList (Proxy :: Proxy '[Int, String]) (Just False)
```

would be a type-correct call of this function, choosing `g` to be `Maybe` and `ix` to be `Bool`. But that can't be correct. We need to pass in something that is sufficiently polymorphic that it works at least for all the elements occuring in the type-level list, or even better, for any possible choice of `ix`. This is what a rank-2 polymorphic type achieves:

```
class TListGen ixs (g :: * -> *) where
  genTList :: Proxy ixs -> (forall ix . g ix) -> TList ixs g
```

This requires the `RankNTypes` language extension.

Now the caller can only pass a function that is polymorphic in the argument type of `g`. So passing `Just False` would no longer work, but passing `Nothing` would be ok.

The definition of the cases is in principle ok, but you can actually remove the `OVERLAPS` pragma and even the proxy argument, because nothing is overlapping, and the `ixs` can be inferred from the result type, as it occurs as an argument to the `TList` datatype:

```
class TListGen ixs (g :: * -> *) where
  genTList :: (forall ix . g ix) -> TList ixs g

instance TListGen '[] g where
  genTList _ = TNil

instance TListGen ixs g => TListGen (ix ': ixs) g where
  genTList g = g :-: genTList g
```

Now we can try to use it:

```
GHCi> genTList Nothing :: TList '[ Int, String ] Maybe
```

Unfortunately, this leads to an error, because there's no `Show` instance:

```
• No instance for (Show (TList '[Int, String] Maybe))
    arising from a use of ‘print’
• In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Defining a `Show` instance for `TList` is possible, but a bit tricky.

I'm not sure whether this is primarily an exercise, but if you're ok with just reusing code, then all this is available in the [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop) package.

Your `TList` is called `NP` (with the arguments being in flipped order), and your `genTList` is called `pure_NP`, so you can write

```
GHCi> import Generics.SOP.NP
GHCi> pure_NP Nothing :: NP Maybe '[ Int, String ]
Nothing :* (Nothing :* Nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! It's half-exercise indeed, but mainly I would like to have less dependencies and keep it simple.